# I can't access the XerainGaming MineCraft server even though it was working yesterday

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I usually play on the Xeraingaming server every day and it works, but mysteriously today it didn't work. I tried to do the Sky Does Minecraft server and it didn't connect either. Then I tried other random servers from the internet and they worked.

Can anyone explain this? And in plain terms because I am not a computer genius. My internet is working fine (since I can post here) but I still can't access my fave server.

Comment: Are you sure they're currently up and running?

Comment: Did you click "Yes" or "Not now" when the game asked you to update? Probably your game and the servers are running different versions now.

Comment: Where are you playing from? What kind of network? Could this be a firewall?

Comment: By the way, the title is wrong. You say you can't access regular MineCraft servers though you actually can. Should that be changed, since googlers/searchers would find a wrong question/answer here?

Comment: If the answer is correct and they've shut down, this is too localized to be of use to anyone else, I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree. Didn't even think about that.

Comment: @fbueckert Sky Does Minecraft is still up though. Looking at a bunch of server graphs at https://mcservers.org it looks like many have a huge drop in players as of today (which is probably because of the 1.5 update) so a general "I can't access my servers!" "Did you just update? That's why" question is probably useful to future users.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Don't we have one of those already?  If not, then, yeah, sure, we can keep this one.  I was pretty sure we had one like that, though.

Comment: @fbueckert I would have thought so, but I don't see one... Maybe we should make a self-answer to handle those, and make sure it's phrased so that people searching will find it?

Comment: Yeah I just checked google as well, and nothing of gaming stackexchange pops up. But what is a decent answer to that? A list of sites which check the status? What if those sites go down? Are they always representable? Is that list complete?

Comment: I don't think there is one definite answer to such question due to the many servers existing.

Comment: @Joetjah It's more to do with what the person does; servers don't automatically update to the latest version, so if the person does, they can't connect because they have a more recent version.  We can't give a definite answer for servers, but we CAN give a definite answer for what people do.  That's the way I read his comment, too, though, at first.  So the interpretation is understandable.

Comment: All right then, I must admit I've started Minecraft only once and I didn't like it. So I actually have no clue what I'm going on about here! I just have some experience with non-company hosted servers so I thought I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

XerainGaming said they'd [close the server](http://xeraingaming.com/?p=593).

The following post was made yesterday on the website:

> Hey everyone!
>
> This week some issues came to our attention involving the server. Over
>   the many months that the server has been active thousands of users
>   have logged on to meet new people, build, have fun & sometimes grief.
>
> As many of you know ‘Gyldenglad’ runs the server on his own PC & with
>   the server being up 24/7 this has been a very generous luxury for the
>   XerainGaming viewers. At the time that the server was created, Andre &
>   I were in no situation to afford or run a server, not only would it
>   have been too expensive but it would have required too much time.
>   Thankfully the generosity of Gyldenglad & the admin/mods enabled our
>   viewers to have a safe, fun place to meet and play.
>
> Earlier this week it came to our attention that the electric costs for
>   running the server & the time it takes to update the server & plugins
>   is too much. At this current point in time it is not feasible to have
>   a running server that can hold up to 80 players.
>
> We have also recently started to see a backlash from banned players.
>   There has recently been a rise in the amount of players who have been
>   banned on the server, unsubbing from our channel, down-voting videos &
>   posting negative or irrelevant comments.
>
> In short, the reasons why we have had to close the server:
>
> - Costs to run the server
> - Time to update the server
> - Backlash from banned players
>
> A huge thank you to every player who has made the server a huge
>   success. Also a huge thank you to everyone who has hosted & moderated
>   the server. It has been amazing to be able to join and play alongside
>   you all, and incredible to see how many people made connections &
>   formed friendships with people around the world.
>
> Danny

I wanted to double check on the forum, but the following statement is given:

> The forum will return soon!
>
> With the recent closure of the XerainGaming server we are making
>   changes to the forum.

This means the server is down right now and this is probably the reason you can't play there.

EDIT: Sky Does Minecraft [should be online.](http://minecraft-mp.com/server-s11009) The XerainGaming server [is indeed offline.](http://minecraftservers.net/server/17919/)

Comment: Indeed, I just connected to Sky Does Minecraft. It's running 1.5.